# Laravel - Route::resource with Route::post - Use both

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I am using laravel 4 and i have requirement like i want below two routes like this:

```
 Route::resource('admin/products', 'ProuctController');
 Route::post('admin/products', 'ProductController@index');
```

And It should treat like `[admin.products.store]` goes to store() and `[admin.products]` goes to index() .

Right now both routes goes to store() function of Product controller .

Is it possible to do like i am doing ??

Comment: try to change first post method and second resource method.

Comment: @KiranKanzar Already tried, but not working

Comment: Have you done a php artisan route:list to check the route names?

Comment: possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23506685/8487424

Answer (score 1):

Resource controllers can be given a subset of actions to register:

```
Route::resource('admin/products', 'ProuctController', [
    'except' => [ 'store' ]
]);
```

source: [How to remove show() function from resource controller in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500002/how-to-remove-show-function-from-resource-controller-in-laravel)

Comment: But i need to use store function as well. Your code will remove the default store method i guess